# How do I make a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

Learning as I go...

I have this functionality built, but I need it as a shortcode. How do I do that?

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' );
$terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

$count = count($terms); $i=0;
if ($count > 0) {
    $cape_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="/term-base/' . $term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ($count != $i) $term_list .= ' &middot; '; else $term_list .= '</p>';
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
```

Comment: What have you researched? Did you read the [Codex Shortcode API entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)? Or the [Codex `add_shortcode() entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
add_shortcode('SHORTCODE_NAME', 'SHORTCODE_NAME_shortcode');  

function SHORTCODE_NAME_shortcode() {

// PUT YOUR CODE HERE


}
```

Then you can just do [SHORTCODE_NAME] and whatever is in the SHORTCODE_NAME_shortcode() function will do its thing.

Comment: in your CODE HERE section, make sure not to use any function that `echo`s the output.

Comment: So, like this? And do I put this in the custom.css?

add_shortcode('CATEGORY_LIST', 'CATEGORY_LIST_shortcode');  

<to be ctd>

Comment: function CATEGORY_LIST_shortcode() {$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' );
$terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

$count = count($terms); $i=0;
if ($count > 0) {
    $cape_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="/term-base/' . $term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ($count != $i) $term_list .= ' &middot; '; else $term_list .= '</p>';
    }
    echo $term_list;
}

Comment: You dont need to put it in caps, I just did that so you could see what to replace. Simply copy the code you've got and paste it where it says //your code here (which it looks like you've done). Then copy the whole function and put it in your themes functions.php file. Then you can use your shortcode in whatever template/page/post you want.